# about CMD Manifest.json and python file

Tags: python, cmd

One of my efriends give me this code,
I typed it in CMD

```
python one.py manifest - -dump-api-response manifest.json - -local-path  “E:\myWork” - -uuid 0
```

`one.py` is a python file.
`myWork` includes some documents.

CMD gives

```
python:can’t open file ‘one.py’ :[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

is there any solution？

Comment: The command runs a file named `one.py`. Without seeing the contents of this file, it is impossible for us to guess what it does

Comment: Are you sure your current folder was the one with `one.py` in it?

Comment: @Nanotage Why does it matter what it does? Python complained that it couldn't find the file in the first place.

Comment: Also, make sure you're not using curly quotes when typing commands. If you need to quote something, use ordinary double quotes.

Comment: The ‘.py’ file can create a list for ‘myWork’ folder, I checked the path quotes but it still doesn’t work. I want to know is it the ‘CMD code’ my friend gives me fault?